# how to use highcharts-angular callback function to get chart object

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have used https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular this official wrapper and try to call the callback function to get the chart object. Unfortunately, though I tried various methods that did not give any proper results as I expect. Also, there aren't many documents that describe the callback function. Can someone let me know how to use the callback function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback didn't work for me either.
I was inspecting the code source and I saw the @Output event emitter called `chartInstance`...
It is also [documented](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#chart-instance):

> component output chartInstance - emitted after chart is created (see demo app and logChartInstance function)

So I've used as a normal output event binding:

```
<highcharts-chart
 [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
 [options]="chartOptions"
 ...
 (chartInstance)="onChartInstance($event)"
 ...
></highcharts-chart>
```

And voilà... I think that is not a definitive solution but as a temporary workaround it works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved in two steps:

1. Add `[callbackFunction]="chartCallback"` in compontent's HTML file (just as presented in the [documentation](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular)):

```
 <highcharts-chart
   style="width: 100%; display: block"
   [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
   [options]="chartOptions"
   [(update)]="updateDemo"
   [callbackFunction]="chartCallback"
   [runOutsideAngular]="true"
 >
 </highcharts-chart>
```

2. Initialize callback in the component's TS:

```
  chartCallback: Function = function(chart) {
    console.log("Chart instance: ", chart);
  };
```

**Live demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-b5420

[Documentation for the callback](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#Chart) (third argument of chart's constructor).

Comment: I tried this way but it did not show actual results

Comment: Please provide a live demo that recreates your case. You can fork my codesanbox demo and use it as a template.

Comment: This method worked great for us until we updated our Angular Version. We went from v8 to v13 so I'm not sure which version caused the callback to "break."